# Help understanding why the dot product of two unit ≤ 1

Tags: vectors

I am a 16 year old High school student and I have just started using Gilbert Strang's Linear algebra book. I have reached the second problem set in the first chapter which is about dot products and angles between vectors and I am stuck on this particular question rather I don't understand. I have tried thinking about this for some time and I can't wrap my head around this proof.

> 24. One line proof of the $|u \cdot U| \le 1$ for unit vectors $u = (u_1, u_2)$ and $U = (U_1, U_2)$
>
> $|u\cdot U| ≤ |u_1|\cdot |U_1| + |u_2|\cdot |U_2| ≤ \frac{u_1^2 + U_1^2}{2} + \frac{u_2^2 + U_2^2}{2} = 1$

I understand $|u \cdot U| \le |u_1| \cdot |U_1| + |u_2| \cdot |U_2|$ but I dont understand the $\frac{u_1^2 + U_1^2}{2} + \frac{u_2^2 + U_2^2}{2} = 1$ part of the inequality.

Comment: Sorry for the sloppy formatting I do not know how to do it properly

Comment: If you know that  $\vec v\cdot \vec w =|\vec v|\,|\vec w| \cos \theta$, the claim is clear.

Comment: Here is the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Much appreciated. Will format question properly next time

Comment: Also, I am so glad to see other young students on here!! I am 16 and in high school myself (a mega high school, actually). Sometimes it can be pretty daunting out here contending with the big folks, but you get used to it eventually $\ddot\smile$ Please continue contributing to our wonderful site!

Comment: Didn't expect to receive such clear answers so quickly. I'd like to thank everyone for answering my question for I have digested the answers and I think I understand fully now. My interest in mathematics only really developed in the past 9 months I hope to continue learning with everyone. And again thank you so much I'll be sure to ask more questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from $2ab ≤ a^2 + b^2$, which follows from $(b-a)^2≥0$. Specifically, you use $a = |u_i|$ and $b=|U_i|$ to see that
$$ |u_i||U_i| ≤ \frac{1}{2} ( |u_i|^2 + |U_i|^2 )$$

The combination is 1 because 
\begin{align} |u_1||U_1| + |u_2||U_2|  & ≤ \frac{1}{2} ( \color{red}{|u_1|^2} + \color{blue}{|U_1|^2} ) + \frac{1}{2} ( \color{red}{|u_2|^2} + \color{blue}{|U_2|^2} ) \\&= \frac{1}{2} ( \color{red}{|u_1|^2 + |u_2|^2} ) + \frac{1}{2} ( \color{blue}{|U_1|^2 + |U_2|^2} ) \\&= \frac12 \|u\|^2 + \frac12 \|U\|^2 \\&= \frac12 + \frac 12 \\&= 1,\end{align}
where $\|u\|=1$ and $\|U\|=1$ are the vector norms of $u$ and $U$.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it looks like they are using the AM-GM inequality.

$(|u_1| - |U_1|)^2 \ge 0\\
u_1^2 + U_1^2 - 2|u_1||U_1|  \ge 0\\
\frac {u_1^2 + U_1^2}2 \ge |u_1||U_1|$

Answer (score 1):

For a dot product, $$\left\lvert {\bf a} \cdot {\bf b}\right\rvert = \left\lvert {\bf a} \right\rvert \left\lvert  {\bf b}\right\rvert \cos \theta$$

Since $\cos \theta$ is always between $0$ and $1$ for interior angles, and since we are working with unit vectors, we know that we know that

$$\left\lvert {\bf a} \cdot {\bf b}\right\rvert = \cos\theta \le 1$$

For $\hat{\bf u}$ and $\hat{\bf U}$ to be unit vectors (the hat helps us remember that), the following must be true: $$u_1^2+u_2^2=1=\left\lvert \hat{\bf u}\right\rvert \qquad U_1^2+U_2^2=1=\left\lvert\hat{\bf U}\right\rvert$$

Since $1=1$, we can say that $$u_1^2+u_2^2=U_1^2+U_2^2 =1$$ Dividing by $2$ gives $$\frac{u_1^2+u_2^2}{2}=\frac{U_1^2+U_2^2}{2} =\frac12$$ so of course $$\frac{u_1^2+u_2^2}{2}+\frac{U_1^2+U_2^2}{2} =1$$

Putting all of this together gives us your (in)equalities.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the inequalities *geometric mean* $\le $ *arithmetic mean* $\le$ *quadratic mean*:
$$\sqrt{uU}\le \dfrac{u+U}2\le \sqrt{\frac{u^2+U^2\strut}2}.$$